# Pong game with large form of setting, want a way to save them

Tags: javascript, html, pong

```js
function saveSettings(form){
   document.cookie = "cWidth=" + form.cWidth.value + ";cHeight=" + form.cHeight.value + ";bSpeed=" + form.bSpeed.value + ";pSpeed=" + form.pSpeed.value + ";pHeight=" + form.pHeight.value + "playTo=" + form.playTo.value + ";" + "movePlayer1Up=" + form.movePlayer1Up.value + ";" + ";movePlayer1Down=" + form.movePlayer1Down.value +";movePlayer2Up=" + form.movePlayer2Up.value + ";movePlayer2Down=" + form.movePlayer2Down.value;
  }
  function loadSettings(form){
   form.cWidth.value = getCookie('cWidth');
   form.cHeight.value = getCookie('cHeight');
   form.bSpeed.value = getCookie('bSpeed');
   form.pSpeed.value = getCookie('pSpeed');
   form.pHeight.value = getCookie('pHeight');
   form.playTo.value = getCookie('playTo');
   form.movePlayer1Up.value = getCookie('movePlayer1Up');
   form.movePlayer1Down.value = getCookie('movePlayer1Down');
   form.movePlayer2Up.value = getCookie('movePlayer2Up');
   form.movePlayer2Down.value = getCookie('movePlayer2Down');
  }
  function getCookie(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
     c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
     return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
   }
   return "";
  }
```

```html
<input type = "button" name = "saveSettings1" value = "Save to #1" style = "font-size:20px;border:none;color:black;background-color:lightblue; border-radius: 3px; white-space: normal; width:40px; height: 25px; position: absolute; font-size: 9px;" onClick = "saveSettings(this.form);">
 <input type = "button" name = "loadSettings1" value = "Load #1" style = "font-size:20px;border:none;color:black;background-color:lightblue; border-radius: 3px; white-space: normal; width:40px; height: 25px;position: absolute; font-size: 9px;margin-left: 44px;" onClick = "loadSettings(this.form)">
```

I am in the process of making a pong game and after making a complicated settings menu, I have encountered a problem; whenever the page is reloaded, all information is lost and the data is reset to the default. I thought of using a submit or some sort of button in the form to save the data but have no experience with php and thus am stuck. This is my game for context. Currently, I am trying to get the bottom right four

```html
function saveSettings(form){
   document.cookie = "cWidth=form.cWidth.value;cHeight=form.cHeight.value;bSpeed=form.bSpeed.value;pSpeed=form.pSpeed.value;pHeight=form.pHeight.value;playTo=form.playTo.value;movePlayer1Up=form.movePlayer1Up.value;movePlayer1Down=form.movePlayer1Down.value;movePlayer2Up=form.movePlayer2Up.value;movePlayer2Down=form.movePlayer2Down.value;";
  }
  function loadSettings(form){
   form.cWidth.value = getCookie('cWidth');
   form.cHeight.value = getCookie('cHeight');
  }
  function getCookie(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
     c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
     return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
   }
   return "";
  }
```

buttons on the settings screen to actually do something

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title>Pong Game by ME</title>
 <style>
  canvas {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body style = "text-align:center; font-size:25px;">
 <script>
  function playGame(form){
   document.getElementById("Settings").style.display = 'none';
   var canvas;
   var ctx;
   var keystate;
   var canvasWidth = parseInt(form.cWidth.value);
   var canvasHeight = parseInt(form.cHeight.value);
   var ballSpeed = parseInt(form.bSpeed.value);
   var playerSpeed = parseInt(form.pSpeed.value);
   var playerHeight = parseInt(form.pHeight.value);
   var playTo = parseInt(form.playTo.value);
   var movePlayer1Up = form.movePlayer1Up.value.charCodeAt(0) - 32;
   var movePlayer1Down = form.movePlayer1Down.value.charCodeAt(0) - 32;
   if  (form.movePlayer2Up.value == "UpArrow"){
    var movePlayer2Up = 38; 
   }
   else{
    var movePlayer2Up = form.movePlayer2Up.value.charCodeAt(0) - 32;
   }
   if  (form.movePlayer2Down.value == "DownArrow"){
    var movePlayer2Down = 40; 
   }
   else{
    var movePlayer2Down = form.movePlayer2Down.value.charCodeAt(0) - 32;
   }
   var player1 = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    score: null,
    width: 20,
    height: playerHeight,
    update: function() {
     if (keystate[movePlayer1Up]) this.y -= playerSpeed;
     if (keystate[movePlayer1Down]) this.y -= -playerSpeed;
     this.y = Math.max(Math.min(this.y, canvasHeight - this.height), 0);
    },
    draw: function() {
     ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
   };
   var player2 = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    score: null,
    width: 20,
    height: playerHeight,
    update: function() {
     if (keystate[movePlayer2Up]) this.y -= playerSpeed;
     if (keystate[movePlayer2Down]) this.y += playerSpeed;
     this.y = Math.max(Math.min(this.y, canvasHeight - this.height), 0);
    },
    draw: function() {
     ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
   };
   var ball = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    vel: null,
    side: 20,
    serve: function(side) {
     var r = Math.random();
     this.x = canvasWidth/2;
     this.y = (canvasHeight - this.side) * r ;
     var phi = 0.1 * Math.PI * (1 - 2 * r);
     this.vel = {
      x: side * ballSpeed * Math.cos(phi),
      y: ballSpeed * Math.sin(phi)
     }
    },
    update: function() {
     this.x += this.vel.x;
     this.y += this.vel.y;
     if (0 > this.y || this.y + this.side > canvasHeight) {
      var offset = this.vel.y < 0 ? 0 - this.y : canvasHeight - (this.y + this.side);
      this.y += 2 * offset;
      this.vel.y *= -1;
     }
     var AABBIntersect = function(ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh) {
      return ax < bx + bw && ay < by + bh && bx < ax + aw && by < ay + ah;
     };
     var pdle = this.vel.x < 0 ? player1 : player2;
     if (AABBIntersect(pdle.x, pdle.y, pdle.width, pdle.height,
      this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side)
      ) { 
      this.x = pdle === player1 ? player1.x + player1.width : player2.x - this.side;
     var n = (this.y + this.side - pdle.y)/(pdle.height + this.side);
     var phi = 0.25 * Math.PI * (2 * n - 1);
     var smash = Math.abs(phi) > 0.2 * Math.PI ? 1.5 : 1;
     this.vel.x = smash * (pdle === player1 ? 1 : -1) * ballSpeed * Math.cos(phi);
     this.vel.y = smash * ballSpeed * Math.sin(phi);
     ballSpeed += 1;
    }
    if (0 > this.x + this.side || this.x > canvasWidth) {
     ballSpeed = parseInt(form.bSpeed.value);
     var isplayer1 = pdle === player1;
     player1.score += isplayer1 ? 0 : 1;
     player2.score += isplayer1 ? 1 : 0;
     this.serve(pdle === player1 ? 1 : -1);
    }
   },
   draw: function() {
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side);
   }
  };
  function mplayer2n() {
   canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.width = canvasWidth;
   canvas.height = canvasHeight;
   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   document.body.appendChild(canvas);
   keystate = {};
   document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
    keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
   });
   document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
    delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
   });
   init();
   var loop = function() {
    update();
    draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
   };
   window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
  }
  function init() {
   player1.x = player1.width;
   player1.y = (canvasHeight - player1.height)/2;
   player2.x = canvasWidth - (player1.width + player2.width);
   player2.y = (canvasHeight - player2.height)/2;
   player1.score = 0;
   player2.score = 0;
   ball.serve(1);
  }
  function update() {
   if (player1.score < 10 && player2.score < 10){
    ball.update();
    player1.update();
    player2.update();
   }
  }
  function draw() {
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
   ctx.save();
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   player1.draw();
   ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
   player2.draw();
   ctx.fillStyle = "white";
   ball.draw();
   var w = 4;
   var x = (canvasWidth - w) * 0.5;
   var y = 0;
   var step = canvasHeight/20; 
   while (y < canvasHeight) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
    ctx.fillRect(x, y + step * 0.25, w, step * 0.5);
    y += step;
   }
   ctx.font="150px Georgia"
   var t = player1.score
   var v = player2.score
   ctx.fillText(t, canvas.width/2 - ctx.measureText(t).width - 20, 100);
   ctx.fillText(v, canvas.width/2 + 20, 100)
   if (player1.score > playTo - 1){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
    ctx.font= "100px Georgia"
    var u = t + " - " + v
    var w = "Player 1 wins"
    ctx.fillText(w, canvas.width/2 - ctx.measureText(w).width/2, 130);
    ctx.font = "150px Georgia"
    ctx.fillText(u, canvas.width/2 - ctx.measureText(u).width/2, 300);
   }
   else if (player2.score > playTo - 1){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
    ctx.font= "100px Georgia"
    var u = t + " - " + v
    var w = "Player 2 wins"
    ctx.fillText(w, canvas.width/2 - ctx.measureText(w).width/2, 130);
    ctx.font = "150px Georgia"
    ctx.fillText(u, canvas.width/2 - ctx.measureText(u).width/2, 300);
   }
   ctx.restore();
  }
  mplayer2n();
 }
</script>
<!-- CANCEROUS CSSING BELOW: BE CAREFULL -->
<form action = "" id = "Settings">
 <h1 style="text-decoration:underline;margin-top: 2px;margin-bottom: 20px">Settings:</h1>
 Field Length:  
 <input oninput = "cWidthOut.value = cWidth.value" type = "range" name = "cWidth" min = "700" value = "1200" max = "1400" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey"><output style = "margin-left: 10px; font-size: 20px;"name = "cWidthOut"></output><p style = "font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Default: 1200</p>
 Field Height:   
 <input oninput = "cHeightOut.value = cHeight.value" type = "range" name = "cHeight" min = "300" value = "600" max = "700" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey"><output style = "margin-left: 10px; font-size: 20px;"name = "cHeightOut"></output><p style = "font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Default: 600</p>
 Ball Speed:   
 <input oninput = "bSpeedOut.value = bSpeed.value" type = "range" name = "bSpeed" min = "5" value = "10" max = "20" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey"><output style = "margin-left: 10px; font-size: 20px;"name = "bSpeedOut"></output><p style = "font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Default: 10</p>
 Paddle Speed:   
 <input oninput = "pSpeedOut.value = pSpeed.value" type = "range" name = "pSpeed" min = "6" value = "12" max = "14" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey"><output style = "margin-left: 10px; font-size: 20px;"name = "pSpeedOut"></output><p style = "font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Default: 12</p>
 Paddle Length:   
 <input oninput = "pHeightOut.value = pHeight.value" type = "range" name = "pHeight" min = "50" value = "100" max = "200" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey"><output style = "margin-left: 10px; font-size: 20px;"name = "pHeightOut"></output><p style = "font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Default: 100</p>
 First to ___ Points:   
 <input oninput = "playToOut.value = playTo.value" type = "range" name = "playTo" min = "5" value = "10" max = "25" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey"><output style = "margin-left: 10px; font-size: 20px;"name = "playToOut"></output><p style = "font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Default: 10</p>
 Left Side Up:   
 <input type = "text" name = "movePlayer1Up" value = "w" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey; width:110px"> <br>
 <p style = "font-size:10px"> This must be a normal key or up/down arrow </p>
 Left Side Down:   
 <input type = "text" name = "movePlayer1Down" value = "s" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey; width:110px""><br>
 <p style = "font-size:10px"> This must be a normal key or up/down arrow </p>
 Right Side Up:   
 <input type = "text" name = "movePlayer2Up" value = "UpArrow" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey; width:110px"><br>
 <p style = "font-size:10px"> This must be a normal key or up/down arrow </p>
 Right Side Down:   
 <input type = "text" name = "movePlayer2Down" value = "DownArrow" style = "font-size: 20px; margin-left:5px;background-color:lightgrey; width:110px"><br>
 <p style = "font-size:10px"> This must be a normal key or up/down arrow </p>  
 <input type = "button" name = "Start" value = "Start" style = "font-size:40px;border:none;color:black;background-color:lightpink; border-radius: 10px; position: absolute; margin-left: -105px;" onClick = "playGame(this.form)">
 <input type = "button" name = "saveSettings1" value = "Save to #1" style = "font-size:20px;border:none;color:black;background-color:lightblue; border-radius: 3px; white-space: normal; width:40px; height: 25px; position: absolute; font-size: 9px;">
 <input type = "button" name = "saveSettings2" value = "Save to #2" style = "font-size:20px;border:none;color:black;background-color:lightblue; border-radius: 3px; white-space: normal; width:40px; height: 25px; position: absolute; font-size: 9px;;margin-top: 28px;">
 <input type = "button" name = "loadSettings1" value = "Load #1" style = "font-size:20px;border:none;color:black;background-color:lightblue; border-radius: 3px; white-space: normal; width:40px; height: 25px;position: absolute; font-size: 9px;margin-left: 44px;">
 <input type = "button" name = "loadSettings2" value = "Load #2" style = "font-size:20px;border:none;color:black;background-color:lightblue; border-radius: 3px; white-space: normal; width:40px; height: 25px; position: absolute; font-size: 9px;margin-left: 44px;margin-top: 28px;">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating a cookie

Since there's no sensitive information here, you could store a cookie.

```
playerHeight = 30;
playerWidth = 10;
document.cookie = "pHeight=" + playerHeight;
document.cookie = "pWidth=" + playerWidth;
```

### Reading a cookie

To read the cookie http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp:
The cname is for example `pHeight` or `pWidth`.
The function below can be used: `getCookie("pHeight")` = "30"

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

### Save Button

To create a save button try:

```
document.getElementById("btnsave").addEventListener("click", saveSettings);
```

### Convenient jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/198z9nk9/10/

Comment: I think I don't understand how that would be implemented. How would you call back the cookie for each individual setting? or would I have to manually code that

Comment: Im sorry, but I don't get what that example means. Could you explain why they assigned a variable name?

Comment: When i try this, I get an error saying getCookie is not a function when I try to run it onclick of the buttons

Comment: More explanation in answer

Comment: I made a function saveSettings1 that does nothing just to test. I then wrote onClick = "saveSettings1(this.form)" in the button attributes, but I get an error saying there is no function saveSettings1

Comment: Where does that go in the code? Apparently "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: Put in a script tag after your form block? It needs to be run once page loads.

Comment: If I wanted to load the save, why isn't this working: 

function loadSettings(form){
   form.cWidth.value = getCookie('cWidth');
   form.cHeight.value = getCookie('cHeight');
  }
it seems to instead just reset the slider back to the middle when I click load - edit - added what my code is now onto the qustion

Comment: `"cWidth=form.cWidth.value"` is incorrect. Use: `"cWidth=" + form.cWidth.value`

Comment: Can you show me how that would be done with multiple pairs of information

Comment: Answer is updated. Like, subscribe, favorite, like my other answers, :P

Comment: Again, I will add a code snippet of what I have now and it is still not working. I will make sure to like everything if I can get this to work >.<

Comment: Changed the cookie part, check the link https://jsfiddle.net/198z9nk9/10/

Comment: How come I am doing the exact same thing as you, yet it is not working 
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=RelLo4P2By

Comment: When you were on jsfiddle, were the alerts you made nescessary?